# Global processing of user input in ASP.NET 5

Tags: validation, user-input, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sanitization

What is the best way to pre-process all user input in ASP.NET 5? By pre-process, I mean the basic things we need to perform e.g. trimming unnecessary spaces, sanitizing data, etc?

I want to handle all user input globally and want to make sure that we never miss it i.e. ALL user input must be pre-processed for security, validation, etc.

Our ASP.NET 5 MVC application also has an API as well so I need to come up with a way to handle all user input whether it came into MVC action methods or API methods.

Comment: Create a middleware?

Comment: Have you considered creating global action filter?

Comment: Yes, I think global action filter is the way to go. I'm trying to figure out if I can use data annotations to mark the fields/properties that can be skipped.